# How to infer index signatures correctly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

It seems that inferring the input arg to a generic index signature doesn't work as expected (or I'm totally missing something ).

How can I make the return type inferred and validate the input correctly?

```
interface Styles {
  contentAlign?: string;
  zIndex?: number;
}

function createTheme<S extends { [key: string]: Styles }>(theme: S) {
  return theme;
}

// this works, foo is marked as invalid
const style: Styles = {
  zIndex: 1,
  foo: 'bar', // <-- invalid
};

// once I try to use the Styles as index signature it allows other properties
const t = createTheme({
  Button: {
    zIndex: 1,
    foo: 'bar', // <-- valid??
  },
});
```

I expect `Type { foo: "bar" } is not assignable to type Styles`, but it seems to be a valid input

Comment: I'd like to accomplish that variable `t` has the inferred type of the object passed in: 

```js
{ 
  Button: { 
    zIndex: number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S extends { [key: string]: Styles }` will mean that `S` can be a sub-type of `{ [key: string]: Styles }`. But this also implies that any property of `S` can also be a sub-type of `Styles`, so this means any given key can actually have more properties than those specified in `Styles`.

Generally in OOP it is allowed to assign a sub-type where a base type is expected, Typescript performs excess property checks only when object literals are directly assigned to a specific type. When assigning to a generic type parameter the compiler will not perform excess property checks as it assumes you want to allow sub-types (After all `S extends {...}` reads any type `S` that extends `{...}`).

In your case since you want to allow any keys, but you don't actually want to disable excess property checks on `Styles` I would use as a type parameter the keys of the object instead of the whole object:

```
interface Styles {
  contentAlign?: string;
  zIndex?: number;
}

function createTheme<K extends PropertyKey>(theme: Record<K, Styles>) {
  return theme;
}

// this works, foo is marked as invalid
const style: Styles = {
  zIndex: 1,
  foo: 'bar', // <-- invalid
};

// once I try to use the Styles as index signature it allows other properties
const t = createTheme({
  Button: {
    zIndex: 1,
    foo: 'bar', // <-- error
  },
  Header: {
    zIndex: 1,
    foo: 'bar', // <-- error
  },
});
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgJ4BsIGdkDeAUMsggPbgTgCCWwA5iAPwBcyuYUoDA3CcgBeASRAATCAA82yEAFcAtgCNo-AL5EiMOSARhglMlAhxIAFQAWEBRAA8AaWRTI4-AAUo5AA7RM9iBgAfAAUYFY27ABKEBRQYg4ANGiYOLiBAJSEAsZgclAgyGHWEOqaAPRlhRbA+ADu5FAA1rhJMOTkyDXICnBNEGLIcPigAG5w9GJEFCCcHCkQ7OjYeMgAvFmkIuJS7ACMCQJt5OwA5Eq9J0kVyLYAtLedIGMTRGr8RNeUSMjChVAYhQ6clwKCKyWW+CGjwkkg4jBApjyKGAYEGWCw5Fq+HIRSgyC8nh8UH0eCmlFmqPWCGMpgglmKwWIpAAQnIwGBKOwmaQhKIYXsDjzkEdTucoJdkNc7g9nsAxMxmAI1ILkAAJEwSKBcgSbPk7ZD7HXC9qii5XSrS5Cy+WK0jK17pXhAA)

Comment: Thanks so much! This works as expected  and glad I learned another useful thing